# MainActivity RecyclerView and Room Database crash - Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

Could someone offer some help please, I have tried using some solutions on Stackoverflow and searching for similar topics but nothing works.

I have a project that uses a bottomnavbar to cycle through fragments. The main activity which is using a fragment has a recycler view running in it. Implemented Room database for a simple note taking function to display with RecyclerView

App crashes after splash screen when launching MainActivity

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());




    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_logbook, R.id.navigation_settings, R.id.navigation_aircraft, R.id.navigation_pilots, R.id.navigation_totals)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);



    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())
            .create(NoteViewModel.class);
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {


            //update RecyclerView
    adapter.setNotes(notes);



        }


    });



}
```

}

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.swiftlogbook/com.company.swiftlogbook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at com.company.swiftlogbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Many Thanks for any advice or help with this.

Comment: Similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462564/error-void-recyclerview-setlayoutmanagerrecyclerviewlayoutmanager-on-a

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your `activity_main.xml` view there is no widget with the id `recyclerView`.
Please check the `ids` in your view or use a type-safe mode of databinding by calling the widget from the `binding` variable instead of findViewById

It could be like this `RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView` instead of `RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(...)`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for helping a novice! I was focusing too much towards the default launch fragment for the app. The recyclerView is populating from my data as well now.